# How to set accept media type in RestTemplate (Spring restful client)

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am getting xml response from the spring restful service by default.
Using RestTemplate in my spring restful client how can I configure the accept media type to JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Rest Service is producing only XML, then I don't think you will be able to accept it as JSON. In that case what you need to do is add the MediaType as `"application/json"` in the Rest Service, along with the existing xml response.

For e.g in Spring Restful Service the annotation would be

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myurl", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

If the Rest Service is producing Json and Xml, then in the rest client you need to do :

```
ResponseEntity<YourClass> apiResp = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, YourClass.class);
YourClass output=apiResp.getBody();
```

Comment: I realized that I was using spring 3.0.x in which the produces and consumes were not present. Now I upgraded my application to latest version of spring and then I am able to get json response as expected.